# Block Rewards for a particular cycle - (cycle + 6) * 4096

Tags: node, baker

In order to find reward for a block in any cycle we use the formula (cycle + 6) * 4096.

Suppose we want to find rewards for 10th cycle then the block in which the rewards would be available is (10 + 6)* 4096 = 65536 , BlockHash - BKnpxH7vFwG91XsBbixDadf8yBGBs9pk8tzGvdTE9HtdG2h76a

When i Query this particular block as below

http://xxxxx/chains/main/blocks/BKnpxH7vFwG91XsBbixDadf8yBGBs9pk8tzGvdTE9HtdG2h76a

I need to to look into "metadata" section for "balance_updates" in order to get the rewards but in "metadata" section i find one section called "deactivated" like below

"deactivated": [

```
        "tz1iYx2zSFkhP2WMpVKQiMNhHoU3auUXAxtt",
        "tz1hwLebmYJgbNtFXUbKJCQMAt16oprCuNaQ",
        "tz1hu1rvo2ehr3RjhptxTqVGZzhGVNjink1z",
        "tz1hjNbTne7k8JosQHavyw3ycwXLNYg6xha5"
```

]

1. What is the "deactivated" section for.
2. In "metadata" -> "balance_update" section there are some records like this

   "balance_updates":

   [

   ```
          {
           "kind": "contract",
           "contract": "tz1hThMBD8jQjFt78heuCnKxJnJtQo9Ao25X",
           "change": "-120000000"
       },

       {
           "kind": "freezer",
           "category": "deposits",
           "delegate": "tz1hThMBD8jQjFt78heuCnKxJnJtQo9Ao25X",
           "level": 15,
           "change": "120000000"
       },
       {
           "kind": "freezer",
           "category": "rewards",
           "delegate": "tz1hThMBD8jQjFt78heuCnKxJnJtQo9Ao25X",
           "level": 15,
           "change": "16000000"
       }
   ```

   ]

-The kind - contract in all the other records for this block is positive
-The kind - freezer in all the records is negative
-The kind - reward in all the records is negative

but for this particular record all are opposite can any one help to understand .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please only ask 1 question per post.*

1. Deactivated are bakers which have been deactivated due to no longer participating in the baking process. These accounts will have to re-register as bakers if they want to bake again.
2. Cycle rewards are found in the *last* block of cycle; not the first. Blocks are numbered 0-4095 in each cycle. When you find this block, "balance_updates" contains all rewards for cycle - 5 and all unfrozen deposits from cycle - 5. If you look at the first block of a cycle, you'll see balance_updates which are the normal updates for the baker of that block.

Note that when looking at blocks pre-Babylon, you will see *level* in balance_updates. This was a bug and fixed in Babylon to correctly label as *cycle*

Comment: yes you are correct the cycle rewards are found in the last block of the cycle but  for cycle 1 the block rewards are not not available at the end of cycle 1 they will be available at (1+6) * 4096 =28,672 as per this https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/baking-rewards-as-operations/1127#1127. Could you please validate

Comment: Yes, correct. If you want to know the rewards for cycle X, look forward to the last block of cycle X+5. If you are looking at the last block of cycle Y, that will contain rewards from cycle Y-5 (which is what I said above). Yes, block 28672 is the last block of cycle 6 which contains the rewards for 6-5=C1

Comment: Thanks @utdrmac your answer helped me . I would like to know one small thing the rewards that are given in the last block of Cycle Y do they contain all kind of rewards like baker , endorsment , double_baking etc..

Comment: Yes. Take a look at block 759890. Look for [this operation](https://tzstats.com/oojd2bBJ5EFqZSfZD27q5tzmZqmqimkzdhkqLpMFyX5cKBuix2i) in the block and you'll see that it has its own balance_updates giving "reward" to the baker.

Comment: I understand the double_baking reward but i wanted to ask does the double_baking reward , baker reward and endorsement reward are given at the same end block of the cycle ever time ?

Comment: Yes, baking and endorsement rewards are given at the end cycle block, every cycle. Looking at the block noted before, it seems double_* rewards are released immediately within the same cycle.